# Count appearances of a value until it changes to another value

Tags: python, pandas, count, frequency

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10, 10, 23, 23, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12], columns=['values'])
```

I want to calculate the frequency of each value, but not an overall count - the count of each value until it changes to another value.

I tried:

```
df['values'].value_counts()
```

but it gives me

```
10    6
9     3
23    2
12    1
```

The desired output is

```
10:2 
23:2
 9:3
10:4
12:1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at "run-length encoding", since that's basically what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.groupby(df['values'].ne(df['values'].shift()).cumsum())['values'].value_counts()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby([df['values'].ne(df['values'].shift()).cumsum(), 'values']).size()
```

---

```
print (df)
values  values
1       10        2
2       23        2
3       9         3
4       10        4
5       12        1
Name: values, dtype: int64
```

Last for remove first level:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
values
10    2
23    2
9     3
10    4
12    1
dtype: int64
```

**Explanation**:

Compare original column by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed with not equal [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) and then add [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for helper `Series`:

```
print (pd.concat([df['values'], a, b, c], 
                 keys=('orig','shifted', 'not_equal', 'cumsum'), axis=1))
    orig  shifted  not_equal  cumsum
0     10      NaN       True       1
1     10     10.0      False       1
2     23     10.0       True       2
3     23     23.0      False       2
4      9     23.0       True       3
5      9      9.0      False       3
6      9      9.0      False       3
7     10      9.0       True       4
8     10     10.0      False       4
9     10     10.0      False       4
10    10     10.0      False       4
11    12     10.0       True       5
```

Comment: i got an error : Duplicated level name: "values", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.

Comment: @Mischa - Then add `.rename` like `df['values'].ne(df['values'].shift()).cumsum().rename('val1')`

Answer (score 9):

You can keep track of where the changes in `df['values']` occur, and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the changes and also `df['values']` (to keep them as index) computing the [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) of each group

```
changes = df['values'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.groupby([changes,'values']).size().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

 values
10    2
23    2
9     3
10    4
12    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

#### `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

pd.Series(*zip(*[[len([*v]), k] for k, v in groupby(df['values'])]))

10    2
23    2
9     3
10    4
12    1
dtype: int64
```

---

#### It's a generator

```
def f(x):
  count = 1
  for this, that in zip(x, x[1:]):
    if this == that:
      count += 1
    else:
      yield count, this
      count = 1
  yield count, [*x][-1]

pd.Series(*zip(*f(df['values'])))

10    2
23    2
9     3
10    4
12    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `crosstab`

```
df['key']=df['values'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
pd.crosstab(df['key'],df['values'])
Out[353]: 
values  9   10  12  23
key                   
1        0   2   0   0
2        0   0   0   2
3        3   0   0   0
4        0   4   0   0
5        0   0   1   0
```

Slightly modify the result above

```
pd.crosstab(df['key'],df['values']).stack().loc[lambda x:x.ne(0)]
Out[355]: 
key  values
1    10        2
2    23        2
3    9         3
4    10        4
5    12        1
dtype: int64
```

---

Base on `python` `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

[ (k,len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(df['values'].tolist())]
Out[366]: [(10, 2), (23, 2), (9, 3), (10, 4), (12, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is far from the most time/memory efficient method that in this thread but here's an iterative approach that is pretty straightforward. Please feel encouraged to suggest improvements on this method.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([10, 10, 23, 23, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12], columns=['values'])

dict_count = {}
for v in df['values'].unique():
    dict_count[v] = 0

curr_val = df.iloc[0]['values']
count = 1
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['values'] == curr_val:
        count += 1
    else:
        if count > dict_count[curr_val]:
            dict_count[curr_val] = count
        curr_val = df.iloc[i]['values']
        count = 1
if count > dict_count[curr_val]:
    dict_count[curr_val] = count

df_count = pd.DataFrame(dict_count, index=[0])
print(df_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `groupby` in `itertools` can help you, for `str`:

```
>>> string = 'aabbaacc'
>>> for char, freq in groupby('aabbaacc'):
>>>     print(char, len(list(freq)), sep=':', end='\n')
[out]:
    a:2
    b:2
    a:2
    c:2
```

This function also works for `list`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([10, 10, 23, 23, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12], columns=['values'])
>>> for char, freq in groupby(df['values'].tolist()):
>>>     print(char, len(list(freq)), sep=':', end='\n')
[out]:
    10:2
    23:2
     9:3
    10:4
    12:1
```

`Note`: for `df`, you always use this way like df['values'] to take 'values' column, because DataFrame have a attribute `values`