# Pandas: Create event counter on a time series, based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new series on my pandas DataFrame to count the number of switch of another value.
Here an example:

[image]

I need a function to calculate the column  `new_counter`. The DataFrame is sorted by `foo` and `date`. The counter increases when the variable `foo` or the variable `baz` change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create helper `Series` for consecutive counter and then pass it to `groupby` with [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
s = df['baz'].ne(df['baz'].shift()).cumsum()
df['counter'] = df.groupby(['foo', s]).ngroup() + 1
```

Comment: Thank you it works.
Can you explain the ne() function?

Comment: @paolof89 - It is function [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) like `!=`, better is see it in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53542712/2901002) how it working.