# Pandas Group by on multiple columns to one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a df

```
session_id  article session_type
  1         a       req
  1         b       req
  1         null    action
  2         home    req
  2         h       req
  2         j       req
  2         home    req
  3         home    req
  3         home    req
  3         r       req
  3         home    req
```

I would like to aggregate to one column as a dict of:
1. unique articles
2.unique session_type
3. count all home that are not consecutive

Output:

```
sess_id agg_col
1      {unique_articles:2,unique_promotion_session:2,non_consectutive_home:0}
2      {unique_articles:2,unique_promotion_session:1,non_consectutive_home:2}
3      {unique_articles:1,unique_promotion_session:1,non_consectutive_home:1}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Storing dictionaries in a python column isn't that useful.

Comment: Why `non_consectutive_home:1}` for `session=2` ?

Comment: @user3483203 - the df should be directed to BigQuery as nested structure, if you  think there is a better technique , I'll glad to know

Comment: @jezrael - you are right, i have update it

Comment: @Moti - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrael - '0.24.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#compare home to mask
m = df['article'].eq('home')
#create consecutive groups and filter only by mask home groups
s = m.ne(m.groupby(df['session_id']).shift()).cumsum()[m]
#counts number of groups, compare by 1 for unique home groups
df['home'] = s.map(s.value_counts()).eq(1).astype(int)
#repalce home and null to NaNs for omit this values
df['article']  = df['article'].mask(m | df['article'].eq('null'))
df['home'] = df['home'].fillna(0).astype(int)

#aggregtae number of unique values with omit NaNs and sum for count 1
df1 = df.groupby('session_id').agg({'article':'nunique',
                                    'session_type':'nunique',
                                    'home':'sum'})
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'article':'unique_articles',
                          'session_type':'unique_promotion_session',
                          'home':'non_consectutive_home'})
print (df1)
            unique_articles  unique_promotion_session  non_consectutive_home
session_id                                                                  
1                         2                         2                      0
2                         2                         1                      2
3                         1                         1                      1
```

---

```
#create DaatFrame filled by dicts
d = df1.to_dict('index')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sess_id': list(d.keys()),
                    'agg_col': list(d.values())})
print (df2)
   sess_id                                            agg_col
0        1  {'unique_articles': 2, 'unique_promotion_sessi...
1        2  {'unique_articles': 2, 'unique_promotion_sessi...
2        3  {'unique_articles': 1, 'unique_promotion_sessi...
```

Comment: can you please clarify the second line?

Comment: @Moti - It is explain more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53542712/2901002), only there ia added [m] for filter by mask - only `home` rows.